# .net maui application: cannot archive from visual studio mac command line

Tags: .net, maui

I am trying to publish my app on the app store.
My project contains of the regular maui project and a middleware.data service that also needs to be build into the archive.

this is my csproj from that middleware.data:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="ITodoService.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Models\TodoItem.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Models\TodoServiceEventArgs.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="MVVM\TodoListViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Services\InMemoryTodoService.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Services\InMemoryUserService.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Services\RemoteTodoService.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Datasync.Client" Version="5.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Async" Version="6.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

As you can see, in the beginning it says the target framework is net6.0.

If I were to add ;net6.0-ios to the target frameworks, i can no longer build the data service.

Now, If I try to archive my ios project over the console:

```
 dotnet publish -f:net6.0-ios -c:Release -r ios-arm64
```

I get:

```
SkillbasedMiddleware.Data/obj/project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-ios'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0-ios' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
```

and

```
The RuntimeIdentifier platform 'ios-arm64' and the PlatformTarget 'x64' must be compatible
```

if I try to archive without the runtime specified i also get:

A runtime identifier must be specified in order to publish this project.

I cant really seem to understand how to archive, can you guys help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the following in the .csproj file to check the RuntimeIdentifier:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios'))">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For more information, you could refer to [Publish a .NET MAUI app for iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/overview?view=net-maui-6.0).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: i did this, this changed nothing unfortunatley...

Comment: Have you worked it out?